# How to get the last 4 modified files in directory Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I often need to parse through the logs of a messy application. This application has many instances so many logs for each instance. For each instance of this application, I need to search the newest 4 files in each log directory to look for files, how can I achieve this? I know how to get the latest file but I don't know how to make it count back 4 times:

```
list_of_files = glob.glob('D:\logs\Worker1\*') # * means all if need specific format then *.csv
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getmtime)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re very close:

```
list_of_files = glob.glob(r'D:\logs\Worker1\*')
list_of_files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
newest = list_of_files[-4:]
```

Comment: I'll try this. If the folder is constantly growing, will it make running this script slower. Do I really lose much with these expressions?

Comment: Will I run into an issue where Python can't handle the size of files with the sort function? I assume there's a limit to how many files you can glob or sort through?

Comment: Python can trivially sort hundreds of millions of row. The slow part will be calling `getmtime`, but I’m not sure how you can get around that. On Unix systems the OS caches that info so it should be quick to fetch it, but I’ve never tried it on Windows. Do you have any control over the files in that directory? Like could you make subdirectories for different time periods?

Comment: BTW, I wrote a Python script to create 10,000 files in one directory on a Mac. The code above ran in about 50ms.

Comment: Yes that code is very good. I appreciate the help. It will do just fine for the forseable future

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you get all the modified times, sort them in descending order, and pick the first 4?

Something like this:

```
files_modified_list = [(f, os.path.getmtime(f)) for f in list_of_files]
sorted_files_modified_list = sorted(file_modified_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
top_4_latest_files = [f[0] for f in sorted_files_modified_list[0:3]]
```

Comment: I worry about if things will slow down getting all files in log folder and then sorting through them. a folder could have 4000 files

Comment: I see, but the max() function you are using is also going to be O(n)...so, there shouldn't be too much of a difference. Perhaps you could save an additional file in your folder that saves the names of the files in a way that lets you easily get the newest files. I will think about it and get back.

Comment: Do you have control over the logging application? If so, you can update a file in your folder every time a file is changed that always stores the 4 latest modified filenames.

Comment: I do but the service is ... quite a handful already. The script I run is a maintenace script so it's not something that would run every day. Maybe once a month to check some entries in the log file. The log folders can grow indefinitely as the service runs indefinitely

Comment: So, the time penalty is probably not a big concern. However, do the log files change once they have been created? If not, then every time you run the maintenance script, you can save the list of files that you have already sorted through. Next time you run the script, only look at the new files and sort through those.

Comment: They change in the sense that it is created daily by UTC time. So when a log is created, it is modifed every minute till the day changes and a new file is created

Comment: Btw, is there a limit to how much glob can handle accompanied by the list methodology you've used. i assume there is a limit to what python lists or glob can sort?

Comment: No limit as such except for how much RAM you have - since you have to store that data in RAM when doing these operations. You have mentioned 4000 files, that should be nothing for today's computers. Just try it out by creating copies of files and see how fast it is for 10k, 100k, 1M files. You should be fine honestly.

Comment: Wait, if these are log files, could you get their date or order from their filenames?